# Matlab + Java: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError when trying to use javabuilder

Tags: java, matlab, matlab-deployment

I've been trying to use Matlab's javabuilder package under Windows XP, but I'm getting a strange error when trying to instantiate any javabuilder class. To illustrate the problem, I've created a simple program that prints the MCRROOT and PATH system variables (to check if they're correctly set) and tries to create a MWCharArray:

```
import com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.*;
import com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MCRConfiguration;

class Main
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       System.out.println("MCRROOT: " + System.getenv("MCRROOT"));
       System.out.println("PATH: " + System.getenv("PATH"));
       System.out.println(MCRConfiguration.isInstalledMCR());
       MWCharArray test = new MWCharArray("Test");
   }
}
```

When I execute the program, the output is:

```
MCRROOT: C:\Program files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v710
PATH: C:\Program files\CollabNet Subversion Client;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v710
false
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MCRConfiguration.getMCRRoot(MCRConfiguration.java:77)
        at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MCRConfiguration$ModuleDir.<clinit>(MCRConfiguration.java:51)
        at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MCRConfiguration.getModuleDir(MCRConfiguration.java:56)
        at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWMCR.<clinit>(MWMCR.java:1447)
        at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.MWUtil.GetUnknownClassID(MWUtil.java:1258)
        at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.MWClassID.<clinit>(MWClassID.java:41)
        at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.MWCharArray.<init>(MWCharArray.java:75)
        at Main.main(Main.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
        at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1937)
        at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MCRConfiguration$MCRRoot.get(MCRConfiguration.java:70)
        at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MCRConfiguration$MCRRoot.<clinit>(MCRConfiguration.java:72)
        ... 8 more
Java Result: 1
```

First of all, are MCRROOT's and PATH's values correct? I've tried google for finding out how to set MCRROOT, but there are conflicting results: some sources say that I should include de version dir, others say the opposite. Also, why is the `isInstalledMCR` method returning `false`? I've double-checked the MCR installation (and even uninstalled and installed it to be sure), so why isn't the library finding it?

Thanks on advance for any help!

Edit: I've also tried setting `MCRROOT` with no version string, and it also fails.

Comment: What version of Matlab are you using?

Comment: I'm trying to execute a pre-packaged jar file, built with Matlab7.1, and installed the 7.1 compiler runtime (with MCRInstaller.exe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, so I'm post a self answer for future reference: Besides adding the javabuilder.jar to the program's classpath, you also have to add the path to the MCR's runtime libraries to the `java.library.path` JDK parameter.

My mistake was that, instead of setting the path as the path to the libraries at the MCR installation directory (On my case, `C:\MATLAB\MCR\v710\runtime\win32`), I copied the runtime directory to my project's dir and used it instead. It seems that the javabuilder library uses the `java.library.path` variable the guess the `MCROOT`, what would explain the weird "StringIndexOutOfBoundsException".

Answer (score 1):

Just wild guessing! Java is messing around with strings, while your 'mcrroot' contains white spaces. I might change the mcr install path to something like *C:\MATLAB\MATLABCompilerRuntime\v710*, omitting any white spaces and special characters.

Comment: I've uninstalled MCR and installed it again at C:\MATLAB\MCR\v710 , but the error persists... thanks for the help, anyway :-)

Comment: Matlab itself can be used as 'mcr' as well. Maybe you give it another try.